# IntelliJ: Unable to have multiple library roots

Tags: javascript, python, intellij-idea

I feel like I'm in a bit of a unique situation as I can't find any documentation on how to make this interaction work.  I have a repository that houses a Flask app that will contain code compiled through webpack from a different root, e.g.:

```
REPO_ROOT/
|-- src/
    |-- client/
        |-- app/
            |-- css/
                |-- styles.css
            |-- js/
                |-- index.js
            |-- index.html
        |-- node_modules/
        |-- package.json
        |-- webpack.config.js
    |-- server/
        |-- .venv/
        |-- app/
            |-- static/
            |-- templates/
            |-- __init__.py
        |-- MANIFEST.in
        |-- setup.py
|-- tests/
|-- requirements.txt
|-- setup.cfg

... other meta files ...
```

The problem I'm running into: when I open this project, `node_modules/` is correctly identified and I get proper completions in my `client/` files, but `server/` doesn't.  After setting up the Python SDK to point at my virtual environment, I get completions in my `server/` files, but it stops `client/` from working!  Then, it incorrectly marks `src/` as the ***library root*** in the Project view.

Question: how do I set up IntelliJ to identify both `.venv` *and* `node_modules` to autocomplete from?  When I run install on `package.json`, it correctly identifies the path where it's at, but still doesn't work.

IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2.1
NodeJS & Python plugins

Some additional things I've tried - deleting the SDK in the plugin, deleting `node_modules/` and `.venv/`, clearing the IntelliJ cache, restarting, recreating the libraries through the UI, and still getting the same result.  As soon as I set the Python SDK, it breaks `node_modules/` from being identified as a ***library root***.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting with this and have come to the conclusion: when installing the flask app into the virtual environment SDK loaded by IntelliJ, it's unable to nest the other library root inside another.

I resolved this by moving my js-specific meta files to the root alongside the py-specific meta files to end up looking like this:

```
REPO_ROOT/
|-- .venv/
|-- node_modules/
|-- src/
    |-- app/
        |-- static/
            |-- css/
                |-- style.css
            |-- js/
                |-- index.js
        |-- templates/
            |-- index.html
        |-- __init__.py
|-- tests/
|-- MANIFEST.in
|-- package.json
|-- requirements.txt
|-- setup.cfg
|-- setup.py
|-- webpack.config.js
```

This required extra config in `webpack` to specify `static/` as my context with an added `dist/` as the output, but at this stage, it works.